# Python iterate over list and join lines without a special character to the previous item

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering if anyone has a sort of hacky / cool solution to this problem . I have a text file like so:

```
NAME:name
ID:id
PERSON:person
LOCATION:location

NAME:name
morenamestuff
ID:id
PERSON:person
LOCATION:location

JUNK
```

So I have some blocks that all contain lines that can be split into a dict, and some that cannot. How can I take lines without the `:` character and join them to the previous line? Here's what I'm currently doing

```
# loop through chunk
    # the first element of dat is a Title, so skip that
    key_map = dict(x.split(':') for x in dat[1:])
```

But I of course get an error because the second chunk has a line without the `:` character. So I wanted my dict to look something like this after correctly splitting it:

```
# there will be a key_map for each chunk of data
key_map['NAME'] == 'name morenamestuff' # 3rd line appended to previous
key_map['ID'] == 'id'
key_map['PERSON'] = 'person'
key_map['LOCATION'] = 'location
```

---

### Solution

EDIT: Here's my final solution on [github](https://github.com/Syntaf/Challenge/tree/master/parse), and the full code here:

**parseScript.py**

```
import re
import string

bad_chars = '(){}"<>[] '     # characers we want to strip from the string
key_map = []

# parse file
with open("dat.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.strip('\n')
    data = re.split('}|\[{', data)

# format file
with open("format.dat") as f:
    formatData = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]

data = filter(len, data)

# strip and split each station
for dat in data[1:-1]:
    # perform black magic, don't even try to understand this
    dat = dat.translate(string.maketrans("", "", ), bad_chars).split(',')
    key_map.append(dict(x.split(':') for x in dat if ':' in x ))
    if ':' not in dat[1]:key_map['NAME']+=dat[k][2]


for station in range(0, len(key_map)):
    for opt in formatData:
        print opt,":",key_map[station][opt]
    print ""
```

**dat.txt**

[View raw here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Syntaf/Challenge/master/parse/dat.txt)

**format.dat**

```
NAME
STID
LONGITUDE
LATITUDE
ELEVATION
STATE
ID
```

**out.dat**

[View raw here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Syntaf/Challenge/master/parse/out.dat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not as elegant, as you requested, but this works

```
dat=[['NAME:name',
      'ID:id',
      'PERSON:person',
      'LOCATION:location'],
      ['NAME:name',
      'morenamestuff',
      'ID:id',
      'PERSON:person',
      'LOCATION:location']]
k=1
key_map = dict(x.split(':') for x in dat[k] if ':' in x )
if ':' not in dat[k][1]:key_map['NAME']+=dat[k][1]

key_map>>
{'ID': 'id',
'LOCATION': 'location',
'NAME': 'namemorenamestuff',
'PERSON': 'person'}
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, write your own generator.

Add in `itertools.groupby` to chunk by groups of text delimited by whitespace breaks.

```
def chunker(s):
     it = iter(s)
     out = [next(it)]
     for line in it:
         if ':' in line or not line:
             yield ' '.join(out)
             out = []
         out.append(line)
     if out:
         yield ' '.join(out)
```

usage:

```
from itertools import groupby

[dict(x.split(':') for x in g) for k,g in groupby(chunker(lines), bool) if k]
Out[65]: 
[{'ID': 'id', 'LOCATION': 'location', 'NAME': 'name', 'PERSON': 'person'},
 {'ID': 'id',
  'LOCATION': 'location',
  'NAME': 'name morenamestuff',
  'PERSON': 'person'}]
```

(if those fields are always the same, I'd go with something like creating some `namedtuples` instead of a bunch of `dict`s)

```
from collections import namedtuple

Thing = namedtuple('Thing', 'ID LOCATION NAME PERSON')

[Thing(**dict(x.split(':') for x in g)) for k,g in groupby(chunker(lines), bool) if k]
Out[76]: 
[Thing(ID='id', LOCATION='location', NAME='name', PERSON='person'),
 Thing(ID='id', LOCATION='location', NAME='name morenamestuff', PERSON='person')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't find `itertools` or regex particularly nice to work with, here's a pure-python solution

```
separator = ':'
output = []
chunk = None

with open('/tmp/stuff.txt') as f:
    for line in (x.strip() for x in f):

        if not line:
            # we are between 'chunks'
            chunk, key = None, None
            continue

        if chunk is None:
            # we are at the beginning of a new 'chunk'
            chunk, key = {}, None
            output.append(chunk)

        if separator in line:
            key, val = line.split(separator)
            chunk[key] = val
        else:
            chunk[key] += line
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that addresses all your requirements. It handles joining of multiple lines, ignoring blank lines, and ignoring junk lines that do not appear within a block. It is implemented as a generator that yields each dictionary as it is completed.

```
def parser(data):
    d = {}
    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            if d:
                yield d
            d = {}
        else:
            if ':' in line:
                key, value = line.split(':')
                d[key] = value
            else:
                if d:
                    d[key] = '{} {}'.format(d[key], line)
    if d:
        yield d
```

When run with this data:

```
ignore me

NAME:name1
ID:id1
PERSON:person1
LOCATION:location1

NAME:name2
morenamestuff
ID:id2
PERSON:person2
LOCATION:location2


junk
and
other
stuff


NAME:name3
morenamestuff
and more
ID:id3
PERSON:person3
more person stuff
LOCATION:location3

JUNK
MORE JUNK
```

```
>>> for d in parser(open('data')):
...     print d
{'PERSON': 'person1', 'LOCATION': 'location1', 'NAME': 'name1', 'ID': 'id1'}
{'PERSON': 'person2', 'LOCATION': 'location2', 'NAME': 'name2 morenamestuff', 'ID': 'id2'}
{'PERSON': 'person3 more person stuff', 'LOCATION': 'location3', 'NAME': 'name3 morenamestuff and more', 'ID': 'id3'}
```

You can grab the lot as a list:

```
>>> results = list(parser(open('data')))
>>> results
[{'PERSON': 'person1', 'LOCATION': 'location1', 'NAME': 'name1', 'ID': 'id1'}, {'PERSON': 'person2', 'LOCATION': 'location2', 'NAME': 'name2 morenamestuff', 'ID': 'id2'}, {'PERSON': 'person3 more person stuff', 'LOCATION': 'location3', 'NAME': 'name3 morenamestuff and more', 'ID': 'id3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add something to lines with no ":".

```
if line.find(':') == -1:
    line=line+':None'
```

Then you won't get an error.